# How can I keep XCOPY from copying more than it should?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, xcopy

I have a script for copying files from one folder to another. The XCOPY command looks like this:

```
 XCOPY /E /Y /V /D:%date% %reportsDataPath% TMP\
```

The date flag is supposed to make it copy only files from the date specified or later, but in the TMP I see that it copied files created earlier. However, it does not copy all the data from the files. Instead it copies the root file and subdirectories without the data they should contain.

Is there an error in my command that makes it copy those files?

Answer (score 3):

`%date%` is giving a bad format for the command, the help says that the `/D` switch expects the format `m-d-y`, while `echo %date%` would give you `Tue 11/26/2013`. Meaning that you need to reformat the date to comply.

I think you can get that fixed with:

```
@echo off

:GetDate
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-3" %%a in ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year') ^
do (
    set mydate=%%b-%%a-%%c
    goto CopyScript
)

:CopyScript
 xcopy /e /y /v /d:%mydate% %reportsDataPath% TMP\
```

**Update #1**

For the sake of future visitors, I believe this update will get you the correct date format regardless of region.  If someone from another locale (outside US and that uses a different format than mm/dd/yyyy by default) can verify, that would be awesome.

**Update #2**

Using powershell, you can also get this (`cmd` commands still work in Powershell, but the overall functionality is massively expanded).

```
Get-Date -Format MM-dd-yyyy
```

Comment: No need for looping, use /D:%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%-%DATE:~6,4%  or even better, use ROBOCOPY instead of XCOPY which is more reliable.

Comment: @WhoIsRich - You may want to double check your command (`%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%-%DATE:~6,4%`), that outputs `1-Tu-/26/` (I copy and pasted it, no fat fingering here).  Looks like it should actually be: `%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~10,4%`

Comment: Ah, forgot that it is dependant on your local time format, so what I posted is correct for me, because I am in the UK and %DATE% is in DD/MM/YYYY where as in the USA %DATE% would probably give you MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: @WhoIsRich - Sorry about that!  Added it to the answer.  Out of curiosity, does the `xcopy /?` say for you that it wants `/D:m-d-y` still?

Comment: Yes, XCOPY still requires /D:m-d-y so atleast that is consistent :) Robocopy has /MINAGE: and wants either the number of days or YYYYMMDD just to make things interesting.

Comment: @WhoIsRich - Good to know, I would tend to use robocopy as well, but never did it to have a mindate.  I usually just do `/d` with nothing.

Comment: @WhoIsRich I too thought of robocopy as an alternative: `robocopy %reportsDataPath% TMP\ /MAXAGE:20131126 /E`. Be aware that [MAXAGE excludes older files](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) then the given date

Comment: If the person has day beforehand like   Tue 26/11/2013 or Tue 11/26/2013 then this thing won't work. Perhaps you need a script that can extract the month/date in month , year e.t.c., and internally checks the date format

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us

Comment: @WhoIsRich - Can you see if my update works for your different formatting?  Been trying to find a way to make it work regardless of region.  Looks like while I was gone, people were suggesting I do that .  Barlop must have missed the two different date formats I had before, but no bother - this should fix it.

Comment: Yep, the WMIC update gives the correct format for me also.

Comment: @nerdwaller yes I saw the two date formats you had for usdate and ukdate in the earlier revision, and my point there was that while the uk format is date in month before month, in contrast to us format which is month of year before date in month, there are still variations that might be set that aren't even region dependent, like having day of the week beforehand. So, that stackoverflow link for example included WMIC and gnuwin32's date.exe which can extract the day for whatever format.  I see you've updated your answer to use WMIC, that's good.

Comment: +1 I like the use of skip with goto. I can verify, it finds day month and year for whatever region you're in, you can check this, if you choose Japan, then do date /t, it shows 2013/11/26 in UK date /t shows e.g. Tue 26/11/2013, It will set mydate=11-26-2013 which is american, and is what xcopy wants apparently, as xcopy /? says /D:m-d-y

Comment: @barlop - Thanks!  It's kind of hacky, but otherwise it does another loop over the output and sets the var to null.  If there's a better way you know, please share - I know the linux shell, not CMD.  Thanks for verifying that it works in other locales.

Comment: @nerdwaller  yeah I checked with exiting a for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728798/exiting-out-of-a-for-loop-in-a-batch-file     seems you've done it the way one is meant to, the other way is exit /b  but that exits the whole batch - which is ok - though the goto way is more flexible by staying in the batch.. cmd's For statements  are the grittiest thing, so, if you know them, you know batch scripting. i've also verified with xcopy, it always wants american with dashes and you give it that, so good there too.

Comment: @nerdwaller if I knew another way to exit a for i'd comment on it here. one odd thing I ran into while googling about exiting a for loop in batch (nothing to do with your batch but related to using goto to exit a loop), is that goto even if in an inner loop, exits all loops. that is mentioned in an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710552/how-to-break-inner-loop-in-nested-loop-batch-script